# Cannot position a GLTF Model in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am having a weird problem with a model when I move either the camera or the model below or above 3.5 the model just disappears.

I am attaching the problem as a GIF down below. This is the code for rendering the model

```
import React from "react";
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {GLTFLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import {DRACOLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader";
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

const mapRange = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => (num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;

export default class Model extends React.Component {
    state = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 1000);
        let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});
        renderer.setSize(1000, 1000);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)

        let x;
        let y;

        // Loader stuff

        const loader = new GLTFLoader();
        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();

        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('/examples/js/libs/draco/');
        loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

        let modelHead;
        const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.3);

        const color = 0xFFFFFF;
        const dirLight = new THREE.SpotLight(color, 0.2);
        const dirLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(color, 1);
        const dirLight3 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.6);
        const dirLight4 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.6);
        const dirLight5 = new THREE.SpotLight(color, 0.6);

        let model;

        loader.load("/model.gltf", (gltf) => {
            model = gltf.scene;
            model.scale.multiplyScalar(3)
            model.position.y = -3.4

            model.rotation.x = Math.PI / 9

            modelHead = model.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0];
            console.log(modelHead);
            scene.add(model)
        }, (xhr) => {
        console.log(xhr.loaded, xhr.total);
    })

        this.mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0)
        scene.add(light)

        dirLight.position.set(-6, 10, 8)
        dirLight2.position.set(5, 12, 0)
        dirLight3.position.set(-4, 0.7, 7)
        dirLight4.position.set(3, 0.2, 9)
        dirLight5.position.set(3, -1.1, 6)

        scene.add(dirLight);
        scene.add(dirLight2);
        scene.add(dirLight3);
        scene.add(dirLight4);
        scene.add(dirLight5);
        camera.position.z = 5;


        const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.update();

        let animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        function handleMouseMove(event) {
            x = event.clientX
            y = event.clientY
            if (model && modelHead) {
                modelHead.rotation.y = mapRange(x, 0, window.screen.width, -0.6, 0.5);
                modelHead.rotation.x = mapRange(y, 0, window.screen.height, -0.4, 0.2);
            }
        }

        document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

        animate();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)}>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the behavior described above

https://www.veed.io/view/007671d8-348b-4129-abf3-3cbfa83088b9